# How to set Alerts for indicators values in MT4 platforms

Tags: mql4, alerts, forex

Let say, that I am scalping the market. I would like to set up alerts whenever the indicators value changes, let say stochastic hit the value of 80/20, RSI changed to below/above 50, MACD changed direction. How do I enable alerts for each of them?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a custom EA.  possibly a custom indicator as well.  I'd be glad to help out i've been interested in scalping for a while now.  I work for jack in the box giftcards.